# Polymer core-elements single import

Tags: polymer

I noticed that polymer has single import files for polymer-elements (https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-elements/blob/master/polymer-elements.html) and polymer-ui-elements (https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-ui-elements/blob/master/polymer-ui-elements.html), but not core-elements.  There is a metadata.html inside Polymer/core-elements (https://github.com/Polymer/core-elements/blob/master/metadata.html), but that definitely doesn't look like a complete list, and the purpose of that file isn't abundantly clear (there are actually several metadata.html files in these repositories, and I'm not sure what they are use for).  Is there an official single import file for polymer core-elements anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point! I've just added one: https://github.com/Polymer/core-elements/commit/231425c

Comment: Perfect.  Out of curiosity what are the metadata things?

Comment: Those are used in our designer tool to populate the component palette.

I'm not sure if we have a public demo right now, but you can look at https://github.com/polymerlabs/designer

Comment: Cool, also, I don't think you want core-docs and core-tests in that list as those aren't actually elements, they are the docs and tests for the core-elements (and the files don't actually exist).  Also, polymer.html itself will be transitively included by all of the core-elements when they need it, so I think that could be omitted as well (the others don't have it).

Answer (score 0):

`polymer-elements` & `polymer-ui-elements` are now deprecated. For now use the single repositories for the `core-elements` & `paper-elements` (the Material Design elements). These are the officially supported element collections for Polymer and they are listed on the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-ajax.html).

Note that this will likely change in upcoming releases where elements may not be in the same collections, but as of 0.5 the [collections of elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements) are mostly complete & listed in the docs.